# Systematic downvotes?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I recently had a bad thread which has now been deleted (by me).

Since then, I'm getting a pattern of down-votes on really old threads, some of which are greater than 3+ months. I believe this is vote-fraud or whatever we call it on StackExchange.

I'm unsure of how to get a mod's attention other than in meta. I'm fearful of retribution across the network as I value my SO account a lot more than ServerFault.

Comment: The serial voting script runs daily at 3 am UTC. I didn't see any suspicious votes on your account today, but I'll take another look after 3 am.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I was worried that the downvotes were coming in too low frequency to trip the script. However there's no other logical reason several posts that are "dead" have been drug back up and down voted all of a sudden. Thanks for checking and your time.

Comment: Did you delete more then that one post?  Because all I see is two down votes.  http://serverfault.com/users/164245/snakedoc?tab=reputation&sort=post

Comment: @Zoredache no, but the downvotes started on dead threads at the same time the offending post was having problems. So they are linked undoubtedly. I'm not active on SF much, so it stands out.

Comment: Right, but this is ~2 votes at the moment.  I often get votes on other questions/answers soon after posting something new.  IMO that is just how things work.  If you post something people find really good/bad, then they might go look at your other posts and vote accordingly.  This is not abuse, so long as they vote based on the merits of the merits of the specific question/answer.

Comment: There are only two downvotes, on two different posts, at very different times. This does not look like serial downvoting.

Comment: thanks for the input fellas. i'm going to keep watching this. so many bitter people on SF quick to turn things personal. it's one thing to disagree, it's another entirely to attack someone for an opinion. thanks again for checking on it.

Comment: @SnakeDoc: I (and others) checked on it using the publicly available tools and again you were found wanting ... there may be a pattern emerging.

Comment: I think @Zoredache nailed it in that sometimes people will look at a vocal user like SnakeDoc and check out their other content.  Someone even answered one of his old questions 2 days ago, presumably because of this.

Answer (score 11):

- You stuck your head above the parapet and were found wanting now people are reviewing your earlier works for similarly incorrect answers.

---

- Moderators have no control over or knowledge of the way that people vote.
- People are free to vote as they please.
- There are checks in place to ensure that any serial {up,down}voting that takes place is automagically reversed.

Comment: Im being downvoted on perfectly good questions and answers. In fact, some had upvotes prior to this. In any event, I didn't know if the script would catch these since they are coming in slow (presumably to remain undetected). But over the course of a week, it may add up. I'll follow up if whoever's doing it doesn't cut it out.

Comment: @SnakeDoc: I see 1 of 3 answers and 1 of 5 questions that have downvotes. I don't know when those downvotes occurred but honestly - stop whingeing and get a life.

Comment: **Im being downvoted on perfectly good questions and answers.** -- in *your* opinion. Others may feel otherwise. There's been plenty of times that I've been downvoted on stuff that I thought was perfectly good. Sometimes I've re-examined a subject as a result of that and decided that I was mistaken, and the downvotes reasonable. There are plenty of times where my more 'trivial' answers have received more upvotes than ones I worked harder on. It's the nature of a site like this, & in the absence of a identifiable pattern of abuse then its something you pretty much just have to live with.

Comment: Whining about downvoting generally doesn't do much to engender respect. Answer a few questions or ask some good ones, and we'll see.

Answer (score 11):

You received ***TWO*** downvotes. One on a question and one on an answer. You also received an upvote on one of those same posts. **This isn't a pattern** and you're up 1 reputation net.

As for getting mod's attention, there's a "Flag" button next to every single post (both questions and answers) and every comment on the site. That's the best way to get a hold of a mod. (If you have a problem with a mod you have to use the "contact" link at the bottom of every page, that goes straight to a Stack Exchange Employee).